# Can you assist me in modifying this code so that it gets compiled in older version of linux

Tags: c, linux, fedora, system-calls, cross-compiling

Below is the relevant code which is part of a C program that compiles and executes fine from **Linux 3.2.6 i686 GNU/Linux**. However when I try to compile it from the below old system, I received the below error. I tried porting the binary to the old system but it can't execute due to **missing /lib/libc.so.6**: version missing. Any help will be much appreciated ! 
Relevant code:

```
 clone((int (*)(void *))trigger,
          (void *)((unsigned long)newstack + 65536),
          CLONE_VM | CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID | SIGCHLD,
          &fildes, NULL, NULL, target);
```

Error:

```
<filename>:262: error: too many arguments to function ‘clone’
```

Old system:

> 2.6.11-1.1369_FC4 #1 Thu Jun 2 22:55:56 EDT 2005 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

Comment: OT: This `(void *)((unsigned long)newstack + 65536)` really should be `((char *) newstack) + 65536`. And why the cast here: `(int (*)(void *))trigger`?

Comment: Which libs does the "old" system come with?

Comment: lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      13 May 20  2007 libc.so.6 -> libc-2.3.5.so

Comment: You need to upgrade to glibc-2.5 / Linux 2.6.17 (from what I've seen so far, the code may be using other stuff that needs an even newer version).

Comment: You seem to have added a comment as update to my answer This got rejected as you should have added this as a "comment" using the "add comment" option below my answer. However I updated my answer to point you to include the appropriate header files.

Answer (score 1):

Function signature:

```
int clone(int (*fn)(void *), void *child_stack,
          int flags, void *arg, ...
          /* pid_t *ptid, struct user_desc *tls, pid_t *ctid */ );
```

In older versions of Linux (v 2.4 and earlier), clone() does not take arguments ptid, tls, and ctid.

I know that your old system says 2.6, but try with:

```
 clone((int (*)(void *))trigger,
          (void *)((unsigned long)newstack + 65536),
          CLONE_VM | CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID | SIGCHLD,
          &fildes);
```

Not sure what it would mean if it works. It would look like your header files don't match your kernel version...

**Edit**

user3118201:

much appreciated ..tried that but now I am getting a different error "undefined reference to `splice'" Ideally I would like to code this function in a way that generates the same results but without the "too many arguments" message which is stoping me from creating the binary. Obviously there is something the old version does not like but I don't have the programming skills to modify it and yet provide the same functionality

My reply:

`splice` was added to  glibc in version 2.5 and in Linux 2.6.17.

The program you are trying to compile has been written for a later version of Linux/libc than you seem to have on the old machine.

There is no easy way around this. You either need to either **upgrade the old machine** or **re-write the code**.

Comment: These differnces should apply for kernel 2.4 and earlier. So as the OP seems to be using 2.6 this should not be an issue, shouldn't it?

Comment: Also it is not clear whether one could simply leave `target` untouched without breaking the program's functionality.

Comment: Version: You are right. I just figured that it could be worth a shot since his system complains about the number of arguments.

Answer (score 1):

A quick research revealed that the chances are not to bad you might be lucky if using

```
__clone()
```

with your ancient libc, instead of

```
clone()
```

To issue the system call do:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE 

#include <unistd.h> /* for syscall */    
#include <sys/syscall.h> /* for SYS_clone */

...

syscall(SYS_clone, 
  trigger,
  ((char *) newstack) + 65536,
  CLONE_VM | CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID | SIGCHLD,
  &fildes, NULL, NULL, target);
```

Comment: Tried that ..  error messages when compiling /tmp/ccOIUx0S.o(.text+0x3f6): In function `trigger', undefined reference to `splice', collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @user3118201: As *Klas* mentions `splice()` is available form kernel version 2.6.17 on. Your "old" kernel definitly is **too** old to go one without significant changes to the sources. However rolling your own replacement for the missing `splice()` should be feasable. See here on what it does: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/splice.2.html that is mainly copying data from one file descriptor to another.

Comment: The error you quote has nothing to with calling `clone`. This is simply another issue you face when back-porting the code to this old environment.

Comment: all comments seem to confirm the only solution is to upgrade the old system then.

Comment: @user3118201: If the missing `splice()` is the only problem you could implement it your own and add it to the back-port. Just out of curiosity: What is the background of having the need to run the program on the old machine?

Comment: sure, it is part of an ethical hacking training course I am doing at the moment (http://www.offensive-security.com/). I am using a publicly available exploit (www.exploit-db.com/download/15704.c) to attempt "rooting" a linux system within my lab. I need to do privilege escalation and have been working on this exploit for the whole day trying to get it to work on the target system.

Comment: @user3118201: The 2nd link is dead.